# Programmatically send to front UIButton in custom created view in swift

Tags: swift

How to send **UIButton** to front programmatically.  Where I have drag and drop UIButton at storyboard UIView and I have created another custom UIView to display  another view after button action is fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of methods of **UIView** that allow you to modify the view hierarchy.

```
bringSubviewToFront:
sendSubviewToBack:
insertSubview:atIndex:
insertSubview:aboveSubview:
insertSubview:belowSubview:
exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:
```

Since your views are already inserted into your superview, you could easily call **bringSubviewToFront:**
 once for each view in whatever order you like.